# Creating a 404 route make all my pages gets no styles

Tags: node.js, express

If i create a route 404:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next)
   {res.status(404).render('404page.ejs')})
```

When i visit any other route like the index, css style gets ignored in all pages.

I already specify the folder route of the css:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Clarification: I'm using ejs instead of html.

Comment: what is the path that you request for CSS file?

Comment: the path is src\public\css\main.css

Comment: I mean from template, how do you link CSS in HTML, what path you have there?

Comment: ohh sry haha, i use ejs with this line ```<%- include('partials/head.ejs')%>``` and that partial include that : ```<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">```

Comment: Clarification: it didn't recognize the public folder

Comment: I found the solution, i copy the following line of code and it works perfectly, ty. ```app.set("view engine", "ejs").use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));```

Answer (score 0):

The order when you set static folder and 404 page matters
make sure to set `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));` first, and after set `app.use(function(req, res, next){res.status(404).render('404page.ejs')})`